# Using path parameter under another dependency in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

In one of the projects, I found a `path` in `pubspec.yaml` that refers to another dependency. What in this case defines this parameter (obviously the path) and how to read this pattern `../../../` ?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart:
    path: ../../../
  http: ^0.13.3
```

Comment: Huh?  It's a relative path.  The package is dependent on the `rxdart` package declared by the `pubspec.yaml` file in the great-grandparent directory.